# Problems trying to read individual elements in a Kinect SkeletonFrame variable

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

We've been struggling with a Kinect tutorial for about a month now, and though we've updated most of the code from Beta2 to v1.8, there's a logic error that we don't have the knowledge to fix or understand.

Basically, a small loop is trying to read each individual element in the skeletonSet variable, but we keep getting the error message "Could not find an implementation for the query pattern for source type 'Microsoft.Kinect.SkeletonFrame'. 'Where' not found".

```
void runtime_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            SkeletonFrame skeletonSet = e.OpenSkeletonFrame();

            Skeleton data = (from s in skeletonSet // <- Here is the error
                             where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                             select s).FirstOrDefault();
            if (data != null)
            {
                SetEllipsePosition(Head, data.Joints[JointType.Head]);
                SetEllipsePosition(leftHand, data.Joints[JointType.HandLeft]);
                SetEllipsePosition(rightHand, data.Joints[JointType.HandRight]);
                ProcessGesture(data.Joints[JointType.Head], data.Joints[JointType.HandLeft], data.Joints[JointType.HandRight]);
            }     

        }
```

Does anyone know a solution or explanation for the SkeletonFrame variable, and what would stop this code from working?

Answer (score 0):

You should not work directly with a `SkeletonFrame` - use the method `CopySkeletonDataTo` to copy skeleton data into an array of Skeletons. After that you can work with the skeleton array. And do not forget to dispose the SkeletonFrame you haven opened.

**1. Define a field in your class which will receive the skeleton data:**

```
private Skeleton[] mySkeletons;
```

**2. Open the SkeletonFrame and copy the skeleton data**

```
    private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        bool haveSkeletons = false
        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            if (null != skeletonFrame)
            {
                if ((null == mySkeletons) || (mySkeletons.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength))
                {
                    mySkeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                }
                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(mySkeletons);
                haveSkeletons = true;
            }
        }
```

**3. Work with the copied skeleton data**

```
       if (haveSkeletons)
       {
          Skeleton data = (from s in mySkeletons
             where s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
             select s).FirstOrDefault();
       }
   }
```